# How to restrict "-f" option while making hg push

Tags: mercurial, push

Is there any option to restrict a user to use `hg push -f`? Because it will remove intermediate commits by other users.

Comment: It's not a good idea asking for responses via email, because then no one else would be able to benefit from the answer. I have removed that aspect of your question. See [Allow users to put their email in posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37956/allow-users-to-put-their-e-mail-in-posts) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, doing `hg push -f` cannot remove intermediate commits. Mercurial is built around an append-only history model and you cannot delete stuff from a server by pushing to it.

When a user does `hg push -f`, then he tells Mercurial to go ahead with the push even though it creates new remote [heads](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Head). To prevent this, you need a [hook](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) on the server that forbids more than a single head. There are listed [several such hooks here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Prevent_a_push_that_would_create_multiple_heads).

With Mercurial 1.6, it is no longer necessary to use `-f` when you push a new named branch. You should instead use `hg push --new-branch`. This is safer since it only allows the creation of new branches, not the creation of multiple remote heads.